# Crystal Reports Set a time variable to null

Tags: sql, null, crystal-reports

In Crystal Reports I have a report with several time columns with values like 10:40:00AM, 1:12:00PM, etc.  There should be a normal progression of the times listed, AppointmentTime, CheckInTime, InRoomTime, CheckOutTime.

Occaisionally the CheckInTime is later than the InRoomTime:
CheckInTime = 2:34:00PM and InRoomTime = 2:10:00PM.

This messes up the calculated WaitTime column (InRoomTime - CheckInTime) because 
it will return a WaitTime of 1416 minutes. (Yes the application should be changed to not allow a CheckInTime after a InRoomTime but I have
no control over it.)

What I thought to do was something like

if{CheckInTime} > {InRoomTime} then set {CheckInTime} to null

so it won't figure in the WaitTime calculation, but I can't figure out how to set a time variable to null. If it is easier to do in T-SQL I can do that instead.

Comment: I'm running Crystal Reports 2013.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don't you instead change your formula for WaitTime to

```
if{CheckInTime} > {InRoomTime} then 0 else
{InRoomTime} - {CheckInTime}
```